# Passing View Controllers With Facebook Login Confirmation

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook, swift

I am completely stumped guys, how do I get my app to push from my login view controller to my home view controller (using swift) when someone successfully logs in with facebook. I know this is a bad inspiration but I would like to make the login experience like Tinder's where you must login through fb to continue into the app. I have the bulk of my application already finished but this login problem has been a huge roadblock. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: What part of pushing the view controller are you having trouble with ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way we did it in our app is in our AppDelegate, load a `MainViewController`.

This view controller always exist on the navigation stack, it is the root view controller.

In the `MainViewController`, we check for the existence of the Facebook session.

If it exists, we show push the normal `LandingPageViewController`, otherwise, if it doesn't exist, we push the `LoginViewController`.

If you're using a standalone Singleton that isn't a view controller, to do your authentication with Facebook, you can post a `notification`, which you should observe in your MainViewController.

Upon receiving this notification, you can perform the push view controller action.

### Note

Below pseudo-code is in Objective C but you can follow along with Swift.

### App Delegate

```
#import "MainViewController.h"

-(void)didFinishLaunchingWithOptions....
{
    // pseudo-code

    MainViewController *mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mainVC];
}
```

### MainViewController.m

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(fbLoginSuccess) name:@"notifLogin" object:nil];

    // check if logged into FB Session
    if(FBSession exists...)
    {
        LandingPageViewController *landingVC = [[LandingPageViewController alloc] init];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:landingVC];
    }
    else
    {
        LoginViewController *loginVC = [[LoginViewController alloc] init];

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:loginVC];
    }
}

// callback method for facebook success
-(void)fbLoginSuccess
{
    // push view controller here
    LandingPageViewController *landingVC = [[LandingPageViewController alloc] init];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:landingVC];
}
```